# retry 'message send failure' with editing

Tags: messages, ios

Here is the situation I get confronted with once in a while. I send an iMessage to more than one person. After a while, I get 'Message send failure'. I search for the reason and I figure I have input a home phone number of the person instead of his iPhone or email address. I go to 'Edit' message but the OS does not allow me to delete that phone number. Is there any other way to remove that number from the 'To' field so that I can resend the iMessage? I don't want to recompose the message (including cut, copy, pasting into a new iMessage)

I am on iOS 6.

Comment: If you don't want to recompose the message, you could copy/cut it to memory (tap and hold the text entry field, Select All, then Copy/Cut, edit the number and paste the message.

Comment: Sorry, rephrased the question. Did not want to cut copy paste. Wanted some way to edit/remove the offending number out from the original iMessage.

Answer (score 1):

The following is only a little less work than simply copying and pasting the original into a new message, but I believe it meets your requirements:

1. Tap `Edit` in the upper-right corner of the message list
2. Tap your message to mark it
3. Tap the `Forward` button at the bottom of the list

This will bring up a sheet that allows you to enter new recipients, with the previously-composed message already in place.